# GeoDjango: AttributeError: function 'GDALAllRegister' not found

Tags: postgis, gdal, geodjango, osgeo4w

Im trying to get started with GeoDjango. I am using this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ tutorial.

When I run "python manage.py migrate"
This error occur: "AttributeError: function 'GDALAllRegister' not found"

I have installed GDAL through the OSGeo4W.

Im on a 32bit Windows7 machine with PostgreSQL 9.3 and postgis 2.1.

What should i do to solve this problem?

---

Unfortunately, I didn't find a resolution. But instead, I found a solution for a mac os x Yosemite machine.

Comment: I am getting the same error with django in a virtualenv. Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: I've tried multiple times getting GeoDjango to work on windows 8. It has something to do with windows not have a C compiler. Poke around the internet there are ways too do it, I just have not figured it out